# Min and Max of $f(x) = 2 \sin(x) + \cos^2 (x)$ on $[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: calculus

Find the absolute minimum and maximum values of,

$$f(x) = 2 \sin(x) + \cos^2 (x) \text{ on } [0, 2\pi]$$

What I did so far is

$$f'(x) = 2\cos(x) -2 \cos(x) \sin(x)$$

Could someone please help me get started?

Comment: So you're looking for where $f'$ vanishes. Note $f'(x)=2\cos x(1-\sin x)$. Also, don't forget about the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/maxima-minima.html

Comment: $f'(x) = 2(\cos x)(1-\sin x).$ This is $0$ if $\cos x=0$ or if $1-\sin x=0. \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method $1$:

Continue from what you have so far,

$$\cos(x)((1-\sin(x))=0$$

Find the stationary point, evaluate the function values at the stationary point as well as the boundaries and conclude the minimal and maximal point.

Method $2$:

\begin{align}
f(x)&=2\sin(x)+\cos^2(x)\\
&=2 \sin(x)+1-\sin^2(x)\\
&=-\sin^2(x)+2\sin(x)+1 \\
&=-(\sin(x)-1)^2+2 
\end{align}

$$-(-1-1)^2+2\le-(\sin(x)-1)^2+2 \le -(1-1)^2+2$$

Answer (score 0):

Without differentiation:
$$f(x)=-(1-\sin x)^2+2; \\
f\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)=-2 (\text{min}); \\
f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=2 (\text{max}).$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint:** $\cos^2x = 1 -\sin^2x \implies f(x) = 2-\left(1-\sin x\right)^2$. Then use the fact that $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$ to obtain the min and max.